# BottomNavigationView covers last item in Listview

Tags: android, listview, bottomnavigationview

Here is my layout for ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.spccheck.CheckSPCFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewspc2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
            >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listviewspc2"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When list contains lot of items, the last one is half displayed because bottom navigation is covering it. How to set listview to be above bottom navigation?

Comment: add margin in bottom 55dp

Comment: listviews are deprecated, you should be using a recyclerview, your relative layout does very little here, the idea of constraint layout is to reduce the need for other nested containers, so you should (and can) probably remove that layout to simplify things, same with the frameLayout